# Parameters Of Type Int Cant Convert

Tags: c#, parameters

```
public List<Client> SearchBy(string proc, string var, string value)
    {
        List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
        var reader = dal.ExecuteProc(proc, var, value);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();
            EnumFactory.ClientType type = new EnumFactory.ClientType();
            EnumFactory.Language language = new EnumFactory.Language();

            Client c = new Client(Convert.ToInt32(reader["ClientID"]), reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Surname"].ToString(), reader["Address"].ToString(), reader["Email"].ToString(), Contacts, reader["Email"].ToString(), type, DateTime.Now, reader(Convert.ToChar(reader["Gender"]), language, reader["AdhocNotes"].ToString(), reader["Status"].ToString(), reader["Color"].ToString());
            clients.Add(c);
        }
        return clients;
    }
```

So im struggling to Convert the ClientID To an Integer, and the Gender to a Char Please Help! I have tried the above conversion. I've Tried this aswel

```
Client c = new Client(reader(Convert.ToInt32(["ClientID"]))
```

But that also doesnt work... Im fairly new to the Usage of Stored Procedure Readers. I have searched and found no results (All of the Sources i found use the above method of converting to an int)

Before You Reply :
Yes the Field, Constructor, and Properties are of int Types and so is the Char Problem.
By the Construction of my parameters you will see my Constructor types are as follows
(int, string, string, string, string, list, string, enum, date, char, enum, string, string, string)

Comment: Remove the `List<Contact> Contacts = new List<Contact>();` to outside the while loop.

Comment: can clientid or gender be null in database?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is very vague. Please describe the error you're seeing.

Comment: It Gives me an error indicating the Types are incorrectly specified in the constructor of the Client c.

Comment: And yes the gender and language are optional (can be null)

Answer (score 2):

If your stored procedure returns an `int` parameter (and it should), you should do the conversion like this

```
int clientId = (int)reader["ClientID"];
```

If the result is nullable integer (or any other type for that matter), the conversion would be like this:

```
int? clientId = (reader["ClientID"] is DBNull) ? (int?)null : (int)reader["ClientID"];
```

If this does not work for you, you should post the exception messages you are getting.

Comment: int clientId = (int)reader["ClientID"];
char gender = (char)reader["Gender"];   This works thanx Alot

Comment: You may change the `else` part to `reader["ClientID"] as int?`, in the *ultra* rare case you change your field "ClientID" to something other than `int` and you *don't* want an invalid cast exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
Convert.ToInt32(reader["ClientID"].ToString()] ,
```

it may throw exception , so better use int.TryParse method as i asked you in the comment , if these fields can be null in database then you shd use Nullable Type.